# tomcat6 shutdown port not listening

Tags: tomcat6, shutdown

I am running tomcat6 on ubuntu9, and i specified shutdown port in server.xml to 8005.
When I do netstat -tln however, i cannot see port 8005 listening.
I can do tomcat6 restart|start|stop no problem.

Why is it not listening on port 8005?

Thanks

Comment: Does this mailing list thread help?: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200901.mbox/%3C4965DBDA.9010505@list-post.mks-mail.de%3E

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem on a previously working Tomcat installation, and in my case it was due to the init() method of a servlet not returning. I was calling a long running method in the init() body and control was never returning to the container. Once I cleared this up, Tomcat started up properly, including listening on the shutdown port.